# How to create a development server for a java web application

Tags: java, docker, jsp, servlets, vagrant

We want to build a java web application (servlets and JSP) with multiple developers for our school project, and I want to optimize the development workflow for a couple of reasons:

1. So we can all work with the same tools and with the same versions (SDK, tomcat-server, MySQL database)
2. prevent the known "but it works on my machine" statement.
3. Set developers up and running quickly , no need to install software on the host machine.
4. Learning purposes.

So what I was thinking to do is to set up a VM and configure it using vagrant to install the proper SDK, tomcat server, and MySQL client-server, maybe even set up a docker-compose file inside the vagrant machine? is that a good idea?

We are not bound to any IDE, and I found some useful vagrant boxes that can help:

https://github.com/ssledz/vagrant-boxes/tree/master/java-dev-environment
https://github.com/timofurrer/java-dev

Can I configure the IDE to use my running tomcat-server when the machine is booting, without the need to configure it manually on the IDE?

Is that an overkill? should we create a simpler development server? if so, how?

Now as you may have guessed we don't have a lot of experience with Java web application development or working as a team, but it's a good opportunity to learn, so feel free to suggest a different approach, the main goal here is to get a development workspace we could all use, and following best practices and industry standards.

How could we achieve that?

Comment: Your post contains 11 questions! It is far too broad in scope, lacks specificity, and is openly inviting opinions which makes it offf topic for SO. Your are asking reasonable questions, but this is not the appropriate place; SO is not a help forum for advice, tips and suggestions. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: OK, I understand this is a broad subject, can you please point me to a better platform or a good resource where I can find answers? The reason my question is not specific and concise is that I understand I'm lacking the knowledge, and I wanted to get some advice or guidance from more experienced developers, so im not really sure how or what to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so What I did was to build on an existing vagrant java-dev box that comes with java and eclipse, and I added a script to install tomcat server 7, and a MySQL database with some mock data.

Here is a link: https://github.com/nati-elmaliach/vagrant-java-development-server

Answer (score 0):

> So what I was thinking to do is to set up a VM and configure it using
>   vagrant to install the proper SDK, tomcat server, and MySQL
>   client-server, maybe even set up a docker-compose file inside the
>   vagrant machine? is that a good idea?

Of course, it is a good idea. Docker became so popular for the same reason.

> will it be easier working with eclipse?

**IntelliJ IDE** and **eclipse** are equally good and popular. Both of them have some features different from each other. So, the choice of and IDE should depend on your experience with the IDE.

> How should we deploy the app to the tomcat server running on the
>   virtual machine? with another server on the host machine?

I suggest you build a CI/CD pipeline using Jenkins. Also, do use some source control software (I recommend **git**).